# How to find the first occurence after a given term in Vim?

Tags: vim

How to locate the second `url` in the following example in vim? (Suppose `url` is the first occurrence in each section)

```
[section1]
 url=

[section2]
 url=      #target search result
```

Comment: `/url<CR>n`...?

Comment: Something like this would work for your example but I'm curious how you like to handle +2 sections? `g/\v\[\w+\]\n url///+1#p`

Comment: You could use: `:0 |exe '/url' | norm! n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to find the first `bar` after the first `foo` would be:

```
/foo/;/bar/<CR>
```

You can use the same method to find the second `url`:

```
/url/;/url/<CR>
```

or:

```
/url/;//<CR>
```

for short.

In this specific case you could also do:

```
/url<CR>
n
```

Comment: The `/foo/;/bar/<CR>` example works perfect, but I didn't understand the second example `/url/;//<CR>`. Does that mean to search for the second occurrence of the `url` in the document?

Comment: `//` reuses the previous search pattern so `/url/;//` is like `/url/;/url/` but with less keystrokes.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, @romainl !

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer that helped you and upvote useful ones.

Comment: I tried early on, but my current "reputation" is too low to give a vote. I am so sorry... T_T

Comment: @cody : Effectively you cannot upvote with a reputation lower than 50. But you can check the answer so your question is marked as 'answered'

Comment: @tinmarino Thank you for letting me know! Just done that! This is a wonderful community to be with! :-)